# How to convert SQL into HQL having union and inner joins?

Tags: java, sql, hql

I wan to convert this **plain SQL query to HQL**. I have an idea that how to convert SQL queries into HQL queries but my query is containing **UNION** and then inner join. So it become tricky to convert it for me.

```
select count(distinct T.id_veicolo) from 
((select distinct C.id_veicolo from (
(select distinct id_veicolo from movement
where id_sede_uscita = 23
and annullato <> 'true' 
and (((inizio >= '2019-01-05' and inizio <= '2019-01-06') and fine >= '2019-01-06') 
or (inizio <= '2019-01-05' and (fine <= '2019-01-06' and fine >= '2019-01-05')) 
or (inizio <= '2019-01-05' and fine >= '2019-01-06') or (inizio >= '2019-01-05' and fine <= '2019-01-06'))) 
UNION 
(select id_veicolo from freeVehicle where id_sede = 23 and inizio <= '2019-01-05' and fine >= '2019-01-06') ) as C) as D 
inner join (select id from parco_veicoli where targa = 'XXX') as R on D.id_veicolo = R.id) as T
```

### Problem Point

If there is only **UNION** present in this query then i could convert this query into 2 sub queries but my problem is that after the **UNION** we again using the inner join. Which is the main problem point for me.

### My Requirement

I want same the result from HQL query as i am getting from this SQL query. I do not want to use SQL query because ***SQL queries doesn't support caching***.

Comment: HQL doesn't support union. So please explain your requirements. Also provide your entity classes.

Comment: Hi @PoojaAggarwal i mentioned my requirement above.

Comment: What particular caching feature are you expecting to work here in this kind of query?

Comment: @LukasEder for now i just want its conversion to HQL, regading the cache i will do that. Do yo have any idea for it?

Comment: I personally think you shouldn't convert this query to HQL. Surely there might be a workaround for this (e.g. using only joins), but you're probably better off with native SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try to figure out its solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need strictly union with inner join then better go for native sql.The resultset can be convereted into POJO objects in a java class.But you will leverage the speed of a native query execution and also just a single db hit.

Comment: Actually in my query i am calculating the count not columns of table. So i think for calculating the count POJO classes are not suitable.